# Differentiate between Silence frame of AMR NB and AMR WB speech codec?

Tags: codec, speech, amr

If I am getting the payload bits, comfort noise parameters only, Is there any way I can differentiate to which codec AMR NB and AMR WB speech codec these bits belong to?

Answer (score 0):

Size of AMR WB Silence frame is 40 bits and AMR NB Silence frame is 39 bits.

Comment: We will always get the frame in bytes. IN this case, its going to be 5 bytes. so the 40th bit expected is 0 in case of AMR NB.(because padding is 0 always). but we can't say conclusively that 40th bit in AMR WB will be 1 always(to differentiate both of them one should be zero and other as 1.)

Answer (score 0):

The frame type of AMRNB SID is 8 while AMRWB's frametype is 9.

Comment: In the question it is mentioned I am getting only the payload bits and no table of content which includes the frame type information.